# In a List. Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'item' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui, mutable

Xcode 12. code and lifecycle are Swiftui.

I've looked at other peoples related questions and it seems like they just dump their entire projects code on here; it's a bit overwhelming to pick what I need from it.
So, I've broken the issue down into the simplest example I can.

The goal is to have numberX iterate when I press the + button.

Thanks in advance!

```
struct InfoData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var nameX: String
    var numberX: Int
}

class ContentX: ObservableObject {
    @Published var infoX = [
        InfoData(nameX: "Example", numberX: 1)
    ]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentX = ContentX()
    var body: some View {
        List(contentX.infoX) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.nameX)")
                Spacer()
                Button("+") {
                    item.numberX += 1 //Eror shows up here <<
                }
                Text("\(item.numberX)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call into contentX and have it update the infoX array directly with the desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the syntax that you're using, `item` is an immutable value, as the error tells you. You can't mutate it, because it doesn't represent a true connection to the array it comes from -- it's just a temporary readable copy that is being used in the `List` iteration.

If you can upgrade to Xcode 13, you have access to something called element binding syntax in `List` and `ForEach` that lets you do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentX = ContentX()
    var body: some View {
        List($contentX.infoX) { $item in //<-- Here
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.nameX)")
                Spacer()
                Button("+") {
                    item.numberX += 1
                }
                Text("\(item.numberX)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you a `Binding` to `item` that is mutable, allowing you to change its value(s) and have them reflected in the original array.

Prior to Xcode 13/Swift 5.5, you'd have to define your own way to alter an element in the array. This is one solution:

```
class ContentX: ObservableObject {
    @Published var infoX = [
        InfoData(nameX: "Example", numberX: 1)
    ]
    
    func alterItem(item: InfoData) {
        self.infoX = self.infoX.map { $0.id == item.id ? item : $0 }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentX = ContentX()
    var body: some View {
        List(contentX.infoX) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.nameX)")
                Spacer()
                Button("+") {
                    var newItem = item
                    newItem.numberX += 1
                    contentX.alterItem(item: newItem)
                }
                Text("\(item.numberX)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, another option where a custom `Binding` is used:

```
class ContentX: ObservableObject {
    @Published var infoX = [
        InfoData(nameX: "Example", numberX: 1)
    ]
    
    func bindingForItem(item: InfoData) -> Binding<InfoData> {
        .init {
            self.infoX.first { $0.id == item.id }!
        } set: { newValue in
            self.infoX = self.infoX.map { $0.id == item.id ? newValue : $0 }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var contentX = ContentX()
    var body: some View {
        List(contentX.infoX) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("\(item.nameX)")
                Spacer()
                Button("+") {
                    contentX.bindingForItem(item: item).wrappedValue.numberX += 1
                }
                Text("\(item.numberX)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!  I'm brand new to code so sometimes I just haven't learned how things work yet.  I look forward to Xcode 13  but I'm in the middle of a course right now and Im worried I won't be able to follow along if I update.  Perhaps my fear is unfounded though.

Comment: Yeah, not a bad idea to keep things comfortable while you're learning.